# Array didn't update after array filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

After i click the remove image if the array have 7 item one remove and i click another it remove another one item but array still 6 it didn't update the last one i delete how can i solve it thanks you for ur time

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-image', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var product_id =$(this).attr('product_id');
        var name =$(this).attr('name');
        var array=$(this).attr('array');
        var arr = JSON.parse(array);
        // confirm("Are You sure want to delete !");
        var arr = arr.filter(val => val !== name);
        console.log(arr);
        var formData = {
            id: id,
            product_id : product_id,
            image: arr
        };

        // $.ajax({
        //     type: "POST",
        //     url: "{{ url('image/delete') }}",
        //     data: formData,
        //     success: function () {
        //         alert('workinggggg');
        //     },
        //     error: function () {
        //         alert('errorrrrrrrr');
        //     }
        // });

        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
```

Laravel Blade

```
  @foreach (json_decode($gallery->image) as $key => $image)
                    <div>
                        <span name="{{ $image }}" id="{{ $gallery->id }}" product_id="{{ $product->id }}" array="{{ $gallery->image }}"
                            class="flex text-red-400 pl-3 image cursor-pointer remove-image">X</span>
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $image) }}" class="pr-5" alt="{{$product->slug}}">
                    </div>
                    {{ var_export($key) }}
                    @endforeach
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A9KI.png)

Comment: In your code I didn't see anywhere you are deleting the item from the array, you are just doing filtering.

Comment: yeah man 
i want to filter the array first and the user update it i will delete it if the user cancel i don't want to delete the image

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correctly gets a filtered array, but it doesn't write the result back to the attribute, and so the next time that code executes, the array is built again from the attribute's value, which still has the original JSON.

So add one statement to this part:

```
    var array = $(this).attr('array');
    var arr = JSON.parse(array);
    var arr = arr.filter(val => val !== name);
    $(this).attr('array', JSON.stringify(arr));   // <---
```

Comment: thanks man 
but it's didn't update the attr idk why 
i think that's what i am missing but it still not working

Comment: Sure it is updating the attribute, but probably you have something else going on. Please edit your question to include a runnable snippet that just has the **minimal** HTML and JavaScript necessary to visibly reproduce your issue. But make sure it is minimal or no-one will look at it.

Comment: yeah man i will update the question